# Plays a role "in" or "at" doing something?

Tags: prepositions

I am writing a scientific article, in which I need to describe the main drivers of a certain phenomenon.

I would like to say that the *driver X plays an important role **at** modifying Y*. But my supervisor corrected me to: *driver X plays an important role **in** modifying Y*.

Which one is correct? None of us are native English speakers, which makes it a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“In” appears to be the more common preposition used after “play a role”:

***[play a part/play a role](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/play-a-part-play-a-role)***

> If something or someone plays a part or plays a role in a situation, they are involved in it and have an effect on it.

> *They played a part in the life of their community.*

> *The U.N. would **play a major role in** monitoring a ceasefire.*

(Collins Dictionary)

Also [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=play%20a%20role%20in%2C%20play%20a%20role%20at&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplay%20a%20role%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplay%20a%20role%20at%3B%2Cc0) shows that ***play a role in*** is the more common collocation.

Comment: It's a metaphor for actors **in** a play.

Comment: Does it make a difference that there is a verb after the prepositions in/at? I see that it sounds good to say "X plays a role in Y". But somehow it sounds better to me to say "X plays a role at doing Y".

Comment: @ouranos - it is largely a question of usage. As Google Books and dictionaries show “to play a role in” (+ ing form or noun) is the more commonly used construction. Play a role “at” is not grammatically wrong, it is just much less common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+role+at+doing%2C+a+role+in+doing+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20role%20in%20doing%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thank you. Now, why did this question get a down vote?

Comment: @ouranos - probably because you a supposed to do your own research and post your results when asking a question. But as a new user  just keep this in mind for future questions.

Comment: Alright. So in this SE, one must answer their own questions. I confess I find it a weird approach for a Q&A forum, having had experience with some other SE sites. But alright, noted. Thanks.